# Stop content scrolling unecessarily

Tags: html, css, scroll, footer, sticky-footer

We have a site at http://cmagics.eu/digitalmagazinepublishing and everything is laid out as we would like it apart from the fact that the page has this annoying scroll of approx 50px even though there is plenty of room for the content to fit into.

How can I stop the page scrolling?
As im not sure what element is causing this, links to the html source and css file are attached below.

html structure

view-source:http://cmagics.eu/digitalmagazinepublishing/

css

http://cmagics.eu/digitalmagazinepublishing/wp-content/themes/responsive2/style.css?ver=1.8.7

Comment: which scroll bar for the slider or for the entire page?

Comment: hi krish, its for the entire page

Comment: its confusing to understand your layout why the white space coming all the way and set the `#container` styles overflow to `overflow:auto;` then explain detail about what ur trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

this might not be 100% the correct solution, but try adding overflow:hidden on the "hfeed" class.

If that does not work, try the same thing on the class that controls the BODY too.

If you install Google Chrome, you can use the dev tools to identify each element and it's assocaited style - makes for debuggin these things much easier.

Comment: Hi Sql, using that on the body does work to stop the scrolling, the only issue is when the content extends beyond the length of the browser you can't see it or scroll.

Comment: how about changing the heights to something less than 100%. I thought this might happen when doing it to the BODY... did it not work on the hfeed class?

Comment: hmm no, it just produces a gap at the bottom of the browser